# jQuery UI Tabs displayed as a vertical grid - Last selected tab breaks design

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Using jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.21.

I am struggling with a bug in my **custom jQuery UI Tabs**. My tabs are not the usual horizontal type, I have them displayed vertically (fixed width) as some kind of grid and my content is on the right (see picture below).

Now my issue is that **everything goes down whenever I select the last tab of the line** (5,10,15,...), and 6 comes under 5. The right picture illustrates the problem :

[image] [image]

The reasons behind the use of Tabs is that I can use approximately 30k lines from a previous project.

Here is my **vertical tabs** :

```
$("#chapters")
    .tabs({ ... })
    .addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
```

My **CSS**, it includes a lot of tests and mistakes and useless parts but still :

```
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav
{
    padding: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: 185px;
    display:inline;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li
{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a
{
    display:block;
    margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;height:100%;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a span
{
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel
{
    padding: 3px;
    padding-left:200px;
    max-width: 548px; /* = 768px -10-paddings */
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-state-active
{
    border: 0 solid #000000;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-selected
{
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    border: 0 solid #000000;
}
```

The **HTML** as requested in comments, it is completely **generated through JS** as there is a lot of algorithms handling these tabs more or less randomly, so here is the structure :

```
<div id="chapters" style="position:relative" class="ui-tabs">
    <ul>
    <!-- li tags coming from a for-loop -->
        <li>
            <a href="#800001"> <!-- random id but matching divs order -->
                <span style="float:left">1</span> <!-- 1,2,3... -->
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- ... -->
        <div id="800001" class="ui-tabs-hide">
            <div id="800001_content">
                <!-- content is loaded here later... (xml parsing, lazy loading system,...) -->
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- end of loop -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is **what I found out** so far :

- updated jQuery to 1.8.0, no change.
- updated jQuery UI to 1.8.23, no change.
- removed ui-tabs-selected live with firebug, no result.
- removed ui-state-active live with firebug, no result.
- removed the borders from the tabs (last part of css), no result.
- removed both ui-tabs-selected AND ui-state-active, the design doesn't break.
- removed ui-tabs-selected and ui-state-active with jQuery in a select or show event.

From my last result I would guess jQuery UI Tabs is applying some CSS to the selected tab that I would need to remove.tab. Unfortunately removing these classes break the tabs functionality, .tabs("option","selected") cannot be set it just goes to the first tab and of course I need it. So I took a look into this widget's code but without any luck...

I would be **open to any kind of solutions**, CSS, Javascript, face palming or even brainwashing. If .tabs() is the source of my problem, I could imagine having .verticalTabs() as a modified clone of .tabs().

I already imagined workarounds by hiding my tabs and making a custom grid with events to select tabs, but I'd rather find another path. :-)

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

JSFiddle to try it out : http://jsfiddle.net/zumproductions/v26pE/

Comment: @krish You can find my HTML structure in my question, nothing special I tried to keep the original jQuery UI Tabs layout.

Comment: If it helps to understand : Selecting tab "50" also breaks the last line, so it's not a matter of width.

Comment: Please provide a sample on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @KristófDombi Here you go : http://jsfiddle.net/zumproductions/v26pE/ I'm glad to see that the issue is the same with default theme and simple code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `.ui-tabs-selected` class from the `li` element the problem goes away.  So its something in there.  In particular it looks like the following styles are the issue:

In the default css:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Your custom css:

```
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-selected {
    border: 0 solid #000000;
}
```

To fix it you can set these styles: `margin-bottom: 2px` and `border 1px solid transparent`

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v26pE/3/

Comment: Wow.. I cannot believe it! I went through so many modifications and style disabling (even that very line) that I missed the obvious. Thank you so much @Nal ! I will implement your solution in my prototype and validate your answer :-)

Comment: You're welcome.  Both styles cause the problem so unless you changed both it would appear as if it wasn't fixed.

Comment: Removing the border was just another attempt to find a solution, no design issue by bringing it back. It works in my prototype, even after my custom lazy loading (we're loading from html, xml and sql sources based on the content type) and even "marking" the tabs with different background colors did not affect your fix. Thanks again, definitely an accepted answer!